# Python/Django: Trouble using Slug in URL

Tags: python, django, slug

I'm building an application using Python 2.7 and Django 1.10 (my first one), and right now I'm having trouble to create the links using slugs for a product detail page.

When I manually type the product URL it works fine (/courses/analise-swot/). It reads the details.html page and builds it appropriately using the information from the database. Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:
Using the URLconf defined in simplemooc.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^ ^$ [name='home']
^ ^contato/ [name='contato']
^courses/ ^$ [name='cursos']
^courses/ ^(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$ [name='details']
^admin/
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, courses/(u'details', (), {u'slug': u'analise-swot'}),       didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my code:

class where I create the slug in models.py:

```
class Course(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField('Nome', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField('Atalho', max_length=100, unique=True)
```

get_absolute_url method in models.py:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return ('details', (), {'slug': self.slug})
```

entire urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.cursos, name='cursos'),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
```

request in views.py:

```
def details(request, slug):
courses = get_object_or_404(Course, slug=slug)
context = {
    'course': courses
}
template_name = 'courses/details.html'
return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method should not return a tuple.

> Define a `get_absolute_url()` method to tell Django how to calculate
>   the canonical URL for an object. To callers, this method should appear
>   to **return a string** that can be used to refer to the object over
>   HTTP.

---

Something like the following will be more like it:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/%s/' % self.slug
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your suggestion worked! I wrote it like this:

    def get_absolute_url(self):
    return "/courses/%s/" % self.slug